# Error: File it is being used by another process, even if closed and disposed

Tags: .net, vb.net, text-files, file-access, read-write

I'm having problems to access a file.

Every 1 second (more or less) my application is calling this procedure to download a sourcecodepage and save it in a textfile,
the problem is sometimes when is called too much for example more than 50 times I get the error:

```
"Can't access file, file it is being used by another process"
```

I've tried to close it and dispose it, but nothing.

EDIT: The file who is causing the error is "OutPutFile" Variable which is a file in %TEMP% dir.

```
' Get URL SourceCode
Function Get_URL_SourceCode(ByVal url As String, Optional ByVal OutputFile As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal delimit As Boolean = False) As String

    Dim SourceCode As String = String.Empty

    If Want_to_cancel_thread Then Return Nothing

    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        SourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd()
        sr.Close() : sr.Dispose()

        If delimit Then SourceCode = Delimit_String(SourceCode, "<div id=""centercol"">", "<!--/centercol -->")

        If OutputFile IsNot Nothing Then

            'File.Open(OutputFile, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)
            'Using TextFile As New StreamWriter(OutputFile, False, Encoding.Default)
            '    TextFile.WriteLine(SourceCode)
            'End Using
            File.WriteAllText(OutputFile, SourceCode, Encoding.Default)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return SourceCode

End Function
```

Comment: Maybe your calling the function too frequently?

Comment: @Sam Yes, but that does not matter because the function does his things and returns a value, so every time I call the function I expect this value to continue, then every time I call to this function should not give any error about the file.

Comment: Ok, are you calling the function from a separate thread? And is the output file different every time?

Comment: @Sam yes I'm calling it from a separate thread, and the output file name is always the same ("%TEMP%\SourceCode.tmp"), the function will replace the file with new text-content (new sourcePages downloaded) but the Outputfile is the same, thanks for your comments

Comment: Your welcome, have you tried implementing a system that checks if the function is finished before calling it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SyncLock` so the working thread locks the object and no other process access the file:

```
'Global variable lock

Dim objectLock As Object = New Object


Function Get_URL_SourceCode(ByVal url As String, Optional ByVal OutputFile As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal delimit As Boolean = False) As String

 Dim SourceCode As String = String.Empty

 'Lock object
 SyncLock objectLock 

 If Want_to_cancel_thread Then Return Nothing

    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        SourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd()
        sr.Close() : sr.Dispose()

        If delimit Then SourceCode = Delimit_String(SourceCode, "<div id=""centercol"">", "<!--/centercol -->")

        If OutputFile IsNot Nothing Then

            'File.Open(OutputFile, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)
            'Using TextFile As New StreamWriter(OutputFile, False, Encoding.Default)
            '    TextFile.WriteLine(SourceCode)
            'End Using
            File.WriteAllText(OutputFile, SourceCode, Encoding.Default)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try

    'End lock
    End SyncLock

    Return SourceCode

 End Function
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try later but I will ask you now: if I need to lock other procedure I need to dispose or something the "objectlock as object" variable? Or I can use it everywhere in all subs just using "SyncLock objectLock " and "end synclock"?

Comment: In this case, you can not lock SourceCode because is not an object, so I declared that Object as a dummy object. If you were not using a fire and forget method like WriteAllText and you were using FileWriter filewriter, you can lock filewriter object. Do you understand?

Comment: nor worked for me :( I'm hetting the same error using synclock

Comment: oops, I found the real problem, I did not disposed other object who reads the file, now all is working without exceptions and without synclock but thanks for all!